# How to define useState variable inside render() reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I am defining useState variables inside render(){} method of reactjs but it is giving me error:Invalid hook call.

```
class ProductDefinition extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
          onProductCreated: undefined,
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
    }
     
    render() {
        const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(undefined);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const uploadButton = (
                <div>
                    {loading ? <LoadingOutlined /> : <PlusOutlined />}
                    <div style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>Upload</div>
                </div>
            );


            return(
            <div style={{ padding: '5px', textAlign: 'left' }}>
  <Form.Item
                                    label="Icon / Thumbnail URL:"
                                    name="productUrl"
                                 >

                                    <Upload
                                        name="avatar"
                                        listType="picture-card"
                                        className="avatar-uploader"
                                        showUploadList={false}
                                       
                                    >
                                        {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" style={{ width: '100%' }} /> : uploadButton}
                                    </Upload>

                            </Form.Item>
                        </div>)

             }
}
```

[image]

What are the ways to define imageUrl and loading variable with useState outside render() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` is the concept of [React Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), and you need to define the useState in the functional component, not class component.

```js
function ProductDefinition() {
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(undefined);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const uploadButton = () => (
                <div>
                    {loading ? <LoadingOutlined /> : <PlusOutlined />}
                    <div style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>Upload</div>
                </div>
            );


    return (
        <div style={{ padding: '5px', textAlign: 'left' }}>
              <Form.Item
                  label="Icon / Thumbnail URL:"
                  name="productUrl"
               >

                  <Upload
                      name="avatar"
                      listType="picture-card"
                      className="avatar-uploader"
                      showUploadList={false}

                  >
                      {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" style={{ width: '100%' }} /> : uploadButton()}
                  </Upload>
          </Form.Item>
      </div>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are get confused between function-based component and class based components.
The hooks are only applicable for function based components.